# Decoding JSON into a PHP array, removing identical entries and encoding back to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to take JSON results from a MySQL query; turn them into a PHP array; remove the identical fields from that array, and turn the array back into JSON. The [1] is the part of the row with the actual JSON in it.

Am I missing something? Having trouble finding any similar questions on the site. Thanks!

```
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($data);

$json = json_decode($data[1], TRUE);
var_dump($json);
print_r($json);

$distinctresult = array_unique($json);
print_r($distinctresult);

$final = json_encode($distinctresult);


{"rows":[{"level":"ERROR","key":"Standard Not found","value":"RI.1.8"},{"level":"ERROR","key":"Standard Not found",{"level":"ERROR","key":"Standard Not found","value":"RI.K.9"},{"level":"ERROR","key":"Standard Not found","value":"RI.K.9"},{"level":"ERROR","key":"Standard Not found","value":"RI.K.9",}]}
```

Here's the MySQL query I'm using:

```
"select distinct d.valueField
    from etllogs t
    inner join etllogdetails d on t.uid = d.etllogID and d.valueField like '%ERROR%'
    where t.transformationName like 'CM Data Extract'
    and (t.timestamp >= (now() - interval 24 hour))
    order by t.timestamp desc;";
```

Comment: What does not work? Do you have several level in your array?

Comment: What does "remove the identical fields" mean? The question is meaningless without knowing what your JSON looks like.

Comment: I don't see any errors in logic. Show us the results of print_r

Comment: @Savageman: couldn't be multilevel, since it's coming from a mysql_fetch_row. it'll be an ordinary 1-d array

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in a database in the first place?

Comment: @MarcB But it's JSON, so it's just a string, and can decode into a multi-level PHP structure.

Comment: So what problems are you actually having?  What results do you expect and what do you get?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: @Barmer whats with storing JSON in a database?

Comment: @dbf What's wrong with storing JSON in a database? I can see several use cases, such as caching generated API responses, or storing schemaless data within an RDBMS -- I'm not generally in favor of storing schemaless data at all, but if you're going to do it, this is a reasonable method.

Comment: @AaronMiller the reason to store JSON in a database can be a million. The OP said nothing about its purpose, those comments are useless just like George W. Bush

Comment: @AaronMiller, I am caching generated API responses in an RDBMS. Usually we get the same few "Standard Not found" codes hundred of times - I'm trying to parse the JSON so only the unique ones show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access array elements in a JSON encoded string (`$data[1]`).
I had success with the following code:

```php
$data = array(0=>array('column1'=>'value1','column2'=>'value2'),
              1=>array('column3'=>'value3','column4'=>'value3'));

$data_json=json_encode($data);
echo"ORIGINAL JSON:<pre>".print_r($data_json,true)."</pre>";

$data_php=json_decode($data_json,true);
echo"PHP ARRAY:<pre>".print_r($data_php,true)."</pre>";

$data_chunk=$data_php[1];
echo"PHP ARRAY CHUNK:<pre>".print_r($data_chunk,true)."</pre>";

$distinctresult = array_unique($data_chunk);
echo"UNIQUE CHUNK:<pre>".print_r($distinctresult,true)."</pre>";

$final = json_encode($distinctresult);
echo"FINAL JSON:<pre>".print_r($final,true)."</pre>";
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7dg-nnb